# How to bind DataTable to DataGrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp3
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public DataTable DataTable
        {
            get { return dataTable; }
            set { dataTable = value; }
        }

        public DataTable dataTable { get; private set; }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataTable = new DataTable("table");

            this.DataTable.Columns.Add("name");
            this.DataTable.Columns.Add("age");
            this.DataTable.Columns.Add("gender");

            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("ddddd", "22", "male");
            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("dfff", "11", "male");
            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("data", "11", "female");

            this.grid1.DataContext = this;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "the error"?

Comment: Binding is case sensitive so make sure you are using the correct case.  Also see msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview

Comment: i am not getting any error message , but i am not able to see my data

Comment: `_dataTable` looks like it might be a field instead of a property. It should be a property. Also, as jdweng has mentioned, "DataTable" is not the  same as "_dataTable".

Comment: @monishtickoo I have just tested this and had no problems, could you post the full code (including your `DataTable` property) please so I can see whats causing the issue

Comment: @Alfie actually i am new to this , so sorry if there are some silly issues

Answer (score 1):

In the `WindowLoaded` method you have referenced your DataTable field as `_dataTable` but defined it as `dataTable`.

Simply update either one of these to match.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only bind to an `IEnumerable`, you should bind to the `DefaultView` property of the `DataTable`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid1" ItemsSource="{Binding _dataTable.DefaultView}" />
```

You may want to remove `_dataTable` (a property name should not begin with an underscore) and initialize and bind to the `DataTable` property instead but the above should work given your current implementation.